# Trying to understand a proof in an example

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I read a proof of Example 3.7 from this [article](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0166864120301139?token=719EA12DA0BD03144778A5576553543D53CBBA4D6EE2DDB15A6117C86F5EB0506B33C8A3CE8B6AB4AD8EC4AC7E975E8F&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230227092023).
[image]

Then, I do not understand the sentence that I highlighted.

> Why $(a_l,b_l)\subset J\subset X_{i_0}$?

I do not think that it is because $J$ is an open interval so that $(a_l,b_l)\subset J$.
Is it because for some $l\in\mathbb{N}$, the open interval $(a_l,b_l)$ is an element from $\{(a_i,b_i):i\in\mathbb{N}\} $  the family of open subintervals of $I=[0,1]$?
Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: $\{(a_i,b_i)\}$ contains all open intervals with rational end points.

Comment: @geetha290krm then, why $(a_l,b_l)\subset J$?

Comment: It is precisely because $J$ is a non-empty open set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open interval $J\subset[0,1]$ is implicitely assumed to be non-empty, hence (by density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$) it contains some interval $(a,b)$ with $a,b$ rationals and $0\le a<b\le1,$ i.e. some $(a_i,b_i).$